# bookmark on kill-buffer-hook

Tags: buffers, hooks, bookmarks

I'm using pdftools when displaying pdfs and it would be nice if emacs could bookmark the pdf with the default filename when I kill that buffer. I've got something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
;; Set a bookmark on kill
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook `bookmark-set)
```

**UPDATE**

I've remarked out all my configuration apart from the add-hook line above. When I open up a pdf file which I want to test with bookmarking on exit I get the following error;

```
bookmark-buffer-file-name: Buffer not visiting a file or directory
Making completion list... [2 times]
File Linux-Voice-Issue-027.pdf is large (73.0M), really open? (y or n) y
File mode specification error: (error "Buffer not visiting a file or directory")
bookmark-buffer-file-name: Buffer not visiting a file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

After putting the code 'chen bin' has suggested I'm getting a lot further. However now when I commit a change using Magit I get the following error and the commit buffer doesn't close, although the commit happens.

```
Type C-c C-c to finish, or C-c C-k to cancel
Saving file /home/map7/testgit/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG...
Wrote /home/map7/testgit/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
string=: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil
Git finished
(No files need saving)
```

**UPDATE**

I now understand that I also need to test if my buffer file I'm closing has an extension.

```
(defun kill-buffer-hook-setup ()
  (if (and buffer-file-name
           (file-name-extension buffer-file-name)
           (string= (downcase (file-name-extension buffer-file-name)) "pdf")
           (yes-or-no-p "Set bookmark with current file name?"))
      (bookmark-set (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) nil)))
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'kill-buffer-hook-setup)
```

Comment: Could you please give details on "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got typo and didn't cover corner cases.

```
(defun kill-buffer-hook-setup ()
  (if (and buffer-file-name
           (file-name-extension buffer-file-name)
           (string= (downcase (file-name-extension buffer-file-name)) "pdf")
           (yes-or-no-p "Set bookmark with current file name?"))
    (bookmark-set (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) nil)))
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'kill-buffer-hook-setup)
```